# Fluent validation with dependency injection patter and passing data

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, fluentvalidation

I want to pass data to fluent validation. I think that is easy, you can do it in constructor. But I don't want to create an instance of validator but inject it and that makes it difficult.

I have :

```
public class someClassValidator : AbstractValidator<someClass>
 {
     public someClassValidator (List<dataModel> data)
     {
     //do validation
     }
    }
 }
    public controller SomeClassController : Controller
    {
    private readonly someClassValidator _someClassValidator;
    public SomeClassController (someClassValidator  someClassValidator )
    {
       _someClassValidator  = someClassValidator;
    }
    
    public void Update(ClassModel)
    {
       var moreData = getSomeApiData (List<dataModel> data);
       var result = _someClassValidator.Validate(model, moreData);
       **// how do I pass data here?**
    }
    }
```

I know you can definitely new ValidatorClass(pasaData) but I am not sure how it works in dependency scenario

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your validator in dependency container. If you are using default DI of asp.net core you can do as suggested in FluentValidation documentation.

```
public class UserValidator : AbstractValidator<User>
{
  public UserValidator()
  {
    RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull();
  }
}

public class UserService
{
    private readonly IValidator<User> _validator;

    public UserService(IValidator<User> validator)
    {
        _validator = validator;
    }

    public async Task DoSomething(User user)
    {
        var validationResult = await _validator.ValidateAsync(user);
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddScoped<IValidator<User>, UserValidator>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      // ...
    }
}
```

https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/di.html

Answer (score 0):

What you need is *RootContextData*. It has a dictionary to put your data into the context and get the data inside the validator. Youre case could look like this:

```
public void Update(ClassModel classModel)
{
   // Creating context by passing the model to validate
   var context = new ValidationContext<ClassModel>(classModel);

   var moreData = getSomeApiData (List<dataModel> data);

   context.RootContextData["MyCustomData"] = moreData;

   // Passing context to validatior instead of the model
   var result = _someClassValidator.Validate(context);
}
```

And to get the data your validator could look like this:

```
// The .Custom method gives you access to the context
// You can get your data from the context.RootContextData dictionary
RuleFor(classModel => classModel.Property)
            .Custom((property, context) =>
            {
                if (context.RootContextData.ContainsKey("MyCustomData"))
                {
                    var moreData= (List<dataModel>)context.RootContextData["MyCustomData"];
                    if (moreData.Failed)
                    {
                        context.AddFailure("You shall not pass!!!");
                    }
                }
            })
```

Here is the [Fluent Validation documentation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/advanced.html)

You can find the full working example [here](https://github.com/ProgBloger/FluentValidation/blob/main/FluentValidation/FluentValidationExamples/Validators/Customization/CustomizedCustomerValidator.cs). Search for the *RootContextData*